# Flash Builder build ios ipa ends in java out of memory error

Tags: ios, ipad, air, flash-builder

I'm using Flash Builder 4.7 with Adobe AIR 3.6 set into an Apache Flex 4.9.1 SDK;

HW system is:
 
iMac,  2,7 GHz Intel Core i5,  8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3,  NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M 512 MB,  OS X 10.8.2 (12C3103)
 
The Flash project consists in an application with a main SWF file which loads other SWF, in cascade.
I've formerly compiled and run the application on an iPad 1, IOS 5.0.1 (9A405), but got on the device the error alert:

"Uncompiled ActionScript
Your application is attempitng to run
uncompiled ActionScript, probably
due to the use of an embedded
SWF. This is unsupported on iOS.
See the Adobe Developer
Connection website for more info."

Then I changed the FB compiler switches, now are set to:

```
-locale en_US 
-swf-version=19
```

Those switche allow to load and debug and use small Flash Builder sample appication on the device.

But, when I try to compile my real application to build an IPA file either for an ad-hoc distribution, either for an debug on device, after some minutes long waiting, I get a Java stuck, with this trace:

```
Error occurred while packaging the application:
 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:753)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:385)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:200)
    at adobe.abc.Algorithms.addUses(Algorithms.java:165)
    at adobe.abc.Algorithms.findUses(Algorithms.java:187)
    at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.sccp(GlobalOptimizer.java:4731)
    at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.optimize(GlobalOptimizer.java:3615)
    at adobe.abc.GlobalOptimizer.optimize(GlobalOptimizer.java:2309)
    at adobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.optimizeABCs(LLVMEmitter.java:532)
    at adobe.abc.LLVMEmitter.generateBitcode(LLVMEmitter.java:341)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.AOTCompiler.convertAbcToLlvmBitcodeImpl(AOTCompiler.java:599)
    at com.adobe.air.ipa.BitcodeGenerator.main(BitcodeGenerator.java:104)
```

I've tried to change the Java settings on FB's eclipse.ini in MacOS folder,

```
-vmargs 
-Xms(various settings up to)1024m 
-Xmx(various settings up to)1024m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=(various settings up to)512m 
-XX:PermSize=(various settings up to)256m
```

but resuls are the same. now settings are as recommended:

```
-vmargs 
-Xms256m 
-Xmx512m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
-XX:PermSize=64m
```

I've changed the Flex build.properties
jvm.args = ${local.d32} -Xms64m -Xmx1024m -ea -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true

with no results; now I'n get back to the standard:
jvm.args = ${local.d32} -Xms64m -Xmx384m -ea -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true

and I have nothing else in mind to try something.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Check `'flashBuilderPath\sdks\sdkVersion\frameworks\build.xml'` `compc` task, set `fork="true" maxmemory="1024m"` and read that topic: http://www.redcodelabs.com/2012/03/eclipse-speed-up-flashbuilder/